# Repeated measures with multiple kinds of repeats

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures

I did a test where a had participants watch video's of animals. There were 3 animals (cat, snake, horse). For each of those animals we had a video in 3 different situations. The participants were asked to rate the animals' happiness in each of the videos.

Now I want to use an ANOVA to test if the rated happiness different in the different situations.

To do this I attempted to use [`ezAnova`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/ez/versions/4.4-0/topics/ezANOVA) but I am unable to find out what I should fill in as parameter values.

The data looks something like this:

```
animal,situation,participant,happyness
cat,   sit_1,    p1,         54
cat,   sit_1,    p2,         191
cat,   sit_1,    p3,         488
cat,   sit_2,    p1,         123
cat,   sit_2,    p2,         546
...
```

My current attempt is this,

```r
ezANOVA(data,dv = happyness,    detailed =  T
        wid = .(animal,participant), within =  situation)
```

I think there are two repetitions, the animals are “reused” and the participants are “reused”. Since some participants have a greater affinity with some animals, and some animals just look “happier” in there normal state, I would like to adjust for that. To this end I added them to the `wid`, but I'm not sure if that even makes sense.

I'm not certain what the "between" and "within" parameters of the repeated measures are (or what those things mean in this context).